# Trouble formatting range in Word using C# Interop

Tags: c#, word-automation

I have an html line, like so:

```
<p>Text<b>bold<i>italic</i>somemore</b>more</p>
```

I am trying to write a function that will properly format this.  I am using the Html Agility Pack.  This is my function so far:

```
    private void write(ref Word.Range range, HtmlNode node, string style = "")
    {
        if (node.Name == "p")
        {
            write(ref range, node.FirstChild);
        }
        else if (node.Name == "b" || node.Name == "i" || node.Name == "u")
        {
            switch (node.Name)
            {
                case "b":
                    range.Bold = -1;
                    break;
                case "i":
                    range.Italic = -1;
                    break;
                case "u":
                    range.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
                    break;
            }
            if (node.HasChildNodes) write(ref range, node.FirstChild);
        }
        else if (node.Name == @"#text")
        {
            range.Text = node.InnerText;
            if (node.NextSibling != null)
            {                    
                write(ref range, node.NextSibling);
            }
        }
    }
```

From what I see, inside of the last else if is where I will be needing to work on either adding ranges, moving ranges, etc, so that when I pass the range back to the function, it will work correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The end result is I just see a bolt and italic word "italic"

Comment: One idea was to use range.insertfile and use the conversion aspect, but I need this automated, I cannot use the popup for converting.